# Common password validation

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a sign-up page in ASP.net and I want to validate a password to make sure that simple passwords are not accepted. e.g "password", "abc123" as these can be easily hacked. I want to do this server side because I dont want to expose any of my in-house password rules to hackers as it narrows down the list of possibilites for them to try
So basically, how would I do the following:

Basically use a list of common passwords and if the password contains any of those phrases (even surrounded by numbers or special chars on either side) then I want to reject the password

Thanks

Comment: please show some source code... what have you tried ? what is not working ?

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't want simple password ? It's a User choice , But you can must say , the password contains one capital letter and one number with above than 8 characters etc .

This is a [Strong Password Validation](http://madskristensen.net/post/Validate-strong-passwords-in-C-and-ASPNET.aspx)

Comment: Forcing 1 number and one capital letter doesn't make a password stronger.  Relevant XKCD: http://xkcd.com/936/

Comment: If you keep idiot people from using idiotic passwords, you're actually reducing the password space, thus making a brute force attack more likely to succeed.

Answer (score 0):

**Criteria:**

- It must be between 8 and 10 characters.
- Contain at least one digit and one alphabetic character.
- And must not contain special characters.

**`passwordStrengthRegularExpression="(?!^[0-9]*$)(?!^[a-zA-Z]*$)^([a-zA-Z0-9]{8,10})$"`**

More **[info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650303.aspx)**

Comment: any idea how to prevent simple passwords as well?

Comment: try to look at the answers here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/125438/where-do-i-find-a-dictionary-for-password-validation